# Why is this query not returning the data( in XQuery, Java)?

Tags: java, xpath, xquery

This is for XQuery used in Java. My code is working with other XML files, but this time it is not returning the required data. The faulty code is below. What is wrong with it? Thanks.

```
String queryString =
                    "declare variable $docName as xs:string external;" + sep +
                    "      for $TRACK in doc($docName)/playlist/tracklist/track " +
                    "   return " +
                    " <track><title>{$TRACK/title/text()}</title>" +
                    " <location>{$TRACK/location/text()}</location></track>";
```

This is the target XML:

```
    <?xml version="1.0"?>
    -<playlist xmlns="http://xspf.org/ns/0/" version="1">
       -<trackList>-<track><location>http://radiotool.com/242.mp3</location><title>New                   York</title></track>
                   -<track><location>http://radiotool.com/243.mp3</location> <title>Chicago Repeater</title></track>
</trackList></playlist>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's probably because the source XML uses a namespace and your XPath doesn't. How about this:

```
String queryString =
                "declare namespace xsp='http://xspf.org/ns/0/'; " + 
                "declare variable $docName as xs:string external;" + sep +
                "  for $TRACK in doc($docName)/xsp:playlist/xsp:trackList/xsp:track " +
                "   return " +
                " <track><title>{$TRACK/xsp:title/text()}</title>" +
                " <location>{$TRACK/xsp:location/text()}</location></track>";
```

Comment: Ok it worked! I had written tracklist instead of trackList lol.